# Fix corrupted exFAT upcase table manually

Tags: sd-card, partition-recovery, filesystem-corruption, exfat, hex-editor

I have recently encountered the error "upcase table is not found" on my SD card formatted with exFAT,
after it worked just fine the previous day.
No tool I tried on Windows or Linux could fix that issue,
even though it seems rather trivial from my investigations.

I know the [supposed contents of the upcase table](http://www.ntfs.com/exfat-upcase-table.htm)
and have [successfully changed the UID through hex editing previously](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/341796).

After making a backup, I inspected the partition in a hex viewer, and what I found where hundreds of entries that looked like an upcase table (between position 0x10000000 and 0x106DFFB on a 400GB SD card in case that is interesting, see example below), almost every single one had some corruption in it though.

[image: corrupted upcase table example]

Can I somehow fix that through manual editing?
Do I have to mind checksums or any shenanigans?

Answer (score 0):

Good News! I finally ran `hexedit` on a `dd` copy of the partition and simply manually replaced the required bytes of the upcase table from 0x01000000 onwards. In the process I found out that all these seemingly extra upcase tables were simply a continuation with extra bits set.

`exfatsck` now shows a different error of which I am unsure whether it is related:

```
ERROR: bad cluster 0 while reading root directory
```

But `testdisk` at least shows some files rather than merely erroring out as before.
Unfortunately most filenames still look garbled, I'll see if I can also fix that...